# Javascript Function GetChatURL is not Defined

Tags: javascript

So these definition problems are usually related to syntax, but I'm not seeing my syntax error. My question is why would my function not be defined when I have it defined onload?

I'm trying to change the onclick event of this link to open a URL with some values I don't have until run time. All of the code below is contained within the body tag.

Here is the HTML

```
<a id ="chaturl" style="position: fixed; top: 55%; right: 0; height: auto;" href="http://someurl" target="_blank" onclick="GetChatURL()"><img alt="Chat" src="~/Content/images/check.png" border="0"></a>
```

Here is a misc RenderSection sitting in between

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Here is the JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("chaturl").onclick = function GetChatURL() {
        var firstName = @(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode((User as OneStop.Core.Entities.Principal).User.FirstName));
        var lastName = @(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode((User as OneStop.Core.Entities.Principal).User.LastName));
        var email = @(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode((User as OneStop.Core.Entities.Principal).User.Email));
        var phone = @(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode((User as OneStop.Core.Entities.Principal).User.PhoneNumber));
        return "window.open(http://someurl/chat.aspx?firstname=" + firstName + "&lastname=" + lastName + "&email=" + email + "&phonenumber=" + phone + ", 'Chat', 'toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,menubar=no,status=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=yes,replace=no');this.newWindow.focus();this.newWindow.opener=window;return false;";
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the function should not *return* the URL, but *open* the URL.

Furthermore, there's no need for the function to be called GetChatURL.
Change

```
document.getElementById("chaturl").onclick = function GetChatURL() {
```

to

```
document.getElementById("chaturl").onclick = function () {
```

Alternatively, you could define the function separately, then you need to change it to:

```
document.getElementById("chaturl").onclick = GetChatURL;
```

and define the function later:

```
function GetChatURL() {
    var firstName = @(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode((User as OneStop.Core.Entities.Principal).User.FirstName));
    var lastName = @(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode((User as OneStop.Core.Entities.Principal).User.LastName));
    var email = @(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode((User as OneStop.Core.Entities.Principal).User.Email));
    var phone = @(System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode((User as OneStop.Core.Entities.Principal).User.PhoneNumber));
    window.open("<url>")
}
```